Hausdorff dimension of neighbourhood of Jordan domain
Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be a bounded domain such that $\partial D$ is a Jordan curve, and for $\varepsilon > 0$ let $D^\varepsilon = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \text{dist}(x,D) < \varepsilon \} $ be its $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood.
Is there anything we can say about the relationship between the Hausdorff dimension of $\partial D$ compared to the Hausdorff dimension of $\partial D^\varepsilon$? In particular, I suspect that taking $\varepsilon$-neighbourhoods has a sort of 'smoothing' property that regularises the dimension of fractal curves, in a similar way to how convolution regularises functions, but am not sure how to show this or if there is any result on this.
